# Proving that the sum of geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues is less than or equal to the dimension of the corresponding vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have trouble understanding the following proof (from Basic Linear Algebra by Blyth and Robertson)

[image]

It seems that the proof is assuming that $\cup B_i$ is a subspace and considers its dimension. Is there something I’m not able to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right, the proof confuses $B_i$ and $E_{\lambda_i}$. Where it says “where each $v_i\in B_i$” it should say “where each $v_i\in E_{\lambda_i}$”, and the displayed equation for $v_i$ should likewise have $E_{\lambda_i}$ instead of $B_i$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But even if I replace $B_i$ with $E_{\lambda_i}$, how is it true that $\cup E_{\lambda_i}$ is a subspace and therefore has a dimension (since the union of subspaces is not necessarily a subspace, right?)?

Comment: @Artus: I didn’t suggest to replace $B_i$ with $E_{\lambda_i}$ everywhere. I said the proofe confuses the two and stated the two instances where $B_i$ needs to be replaced by $E_{\lambda_i}$. No instance of $\bigcup E_{\lambda_i}$ results.

Comment: To clarify what’s confusing me…I’m having trouble understanding the last equation $d_1 + d_2+ \cdots + d_k \leq | \cup E_{\lambda_i}  | \leq n$. Is it saying that $d_1 + \cdots | d_k$ is the dimension of $\cup E_{\lambda_i}$. If so, then is it assuming that $ \cup E_{\lambda_i}$ is a subspace (since we’re considering its dimension)?

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood what I referred to as “the displayed equation for $v_i$”. That refers to the equation for $v_i$, i.e. the last one on p. $159$, not to the equation and inequality on p. $160$ (which doesn’t contain $v_i$). So the $B_i$ on p. $160$ stays as it is.